# Creating jar file in IntelliJ Idea 2018 - Run Jar Error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar, executable-jar

I have an issue. I've created `JavaFX` application in `IntelliJ Idea 2018`, `Java 8`. I've built artifacts to get the executive jar file, and it have completed without any error. However, if I try run my application in `Windows Command Line`, it will occur an error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

My `Main.class` is located obviously in `sample` package.
I've checked also `Application class` in `Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Java FX`. Naturally, my application work properly, and it can be built without any error.
Have you ever had this kind of issue?
Thanks for help :)

Comment: What is the command you are using? You can specify the entry point by running a jar like this:  java -cp MyJar.jar com.mycomp.myproj.dir.MainClass

Comment: https://www.programmergate.com/run-jar-file-command-line/

Comment: What JDK version is used to run it in the command line? Can you share the jar file?